# How can I get Linkskip to work for the below error when Linker behavior is set to "Link Framework SDKs Only"

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm getting the following error when the Linker Behavior is set to "Link Framework SDKs Only".

Can't resolve the reference 'System.Void Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver::set_IgnoreSerializableAttribute(System.Boolean)', referenced from the method 'System.Void System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonContractResolver::.ctor(System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeFormatter)' in 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'.

My build compiles when the linker Behavior is set to "Don't Link".

I've tried:

--linkskip=System.Void Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver

--linkskip=System.Void Newtonsoft.Json

--linkskip=System.Void

--linkskip=Newtonsoft.Json

--linkskip=System.Void System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonContractResolver

--linkskip=System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeFormatter

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Can you ensure you update your NewtonSoft.Json to the latest available package?

Comment: Does this error happen when the Linker is set to `Don't Link`?

Comment: @BrandonMinnick no, when I don't link the app compiles fine.